# page numbering not just on chapter pages - scrreptr

Tags: page-numbering

Here is my document header.
What i want to achieve is to have page numbers on every page. So far I got the page numbers just on the first page of each chapter. The introductory stuff has Roman letters while I switch to arabics afterwards.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,numbers=noenddot,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,appendixprefix ]{scrreptr}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{2} 
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\input{0_SymVZ2}
\printnomenclature[2.5cm]
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\setcounter{page}{1} 
\input{1_Introduction}
\newpage
\input{Theory}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I can’t reproduce the described behavior, please check your (kind of) [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) again …

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but could you please explain what the problem was? If it was just a typo in your code or something like that we may close this question as “too localized” …

Comment: Your example works perfectly, when I am implementing it standalone. However, when I put this in the preamble of my thesis, it still only prints pagenumbers on the first chapter pages.E.g. I have a roman number on the first page of the Content, but on the second page of content the number is missing. Same holds true for the introduction. Can it be that this procedure has problems when I use \input{subfile} in my overall document? I am totally puzzled.

Comment: No, the `\inputs` are no problem. Is there other text on the unnumbered pages? Since, empty pages don’t get a number, while they are counted though … if this is not the problem you can try to comment out parts of your code and recompile until the error disappears. Thats how to find out which line causes this error. In the above MWE I can’t see errors (except the ones I mentioned in my answer).

Comment: Problem solved. No clue how it came there, but within the first subchapter, there was a `\pagestyle{empty}`, which suppressed all following page marks, except the ones of the chapters! Tobi thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: This is because chapters have their own page style (`plain`), which usually includes the pagination but not the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can’t see any problems with your code, except that you misspelled the document class (must be `scrreprt`) and a missing `\begin{document}`.

With this

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,numbers=noenddot,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,appendixprefix ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{lipsum}% blind text

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{2} 
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

I can see page numbers on all pages.

[image: page numbers]